# Getting Following error when uploading app to google play

Tags: android

I'm receiving following error while uploading app into google play. Unable to figure out the reason.

`This configuration cannot be published for the following reason(s):
A device with API levels in range 8+ is eligible to receive version 2, which is optimized for higher API levels, but actually receives version 3 because it has a higher version code. This would occur when 
Screen layouts containing any of [small, normal, large, xlarge] and 
Features containing all of [android.hardware.LOCATION, android.hardware.location.GPS, android.hardware.location.NETWORK, android.hardware.TOUCHSCREEN].
A device upgrading from API levels = 7 to API levels in range 8+ would become eligible to receive version 2, which is optimized for higher API levels, but would actually receive version 3 because it has a higher version code. This would occur when 
Screen layouts containing any of [small, normal, large, xlarge] and 
Features containing all of [android.hardware.LOCATION, android.hardware.location.GPS, android.hardware.location.NETWORK, android.hardware.TOUCHSCREEN]`

Comment: Is it an update you are trying to upload, or a completely new application?

Comment: @hundeva It's an update

Comment: Then you probably messed up the version codes. Check it in your manifest, my bet is you have versioncode 3 already uploaded, and now you want to upload with versioncode 2, which is invalid. If this is the case, try change 2 for 4.

Comment: @hundeva ok let me check and try

Comment: @hundeva is it necessary to change version code for every try of uploading app?

Comment: @hundeva I was messed with version codes :) thanks for your help :)

Comment: Glad to help, I posted it as an answer as well. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have your version codes messed up. Check in your manifest, and make the neccessary changes.

It is also neccessary to update the version codes with every uploaded version of your application, since Google Play uses them to determine the life cycle of your app.

For more, check [the official android guidelines](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/versioning.html).